# How to sort a object containing a mix of numbers and strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, object, lodash

I have an object that looks like this (for example):

```
const items = [{ name: 'LFB 1Y GF'}, {name: 'LFB 3M GF'}, {name: 'LFB 2Y GF'}, {name: 'LFB 10Y GF'}, {name: 'LFB 5Y GF'}]
```

What i need the object to look like after the sorting is:

```
const items = [{ name: 'LFB 3M GF'}, {name: 'LFB 1Y GF'}, {name: 'LFB 2Y GF'}, {name: 'LFB 5Y GF'}, {name: 'LFB 10Y GF'}]
```

I tried lodash '_.sortBy()' but it's outputting:

```
const items =[{ name: 'LFB 10Y GF'}, {name: 'LFB 1Y GF'}, {name: 'LFB 2Y GF'}, {name: 'LFB 3M GF'}, {name: 'LFB 5Y GF'}]
```

Is there any way I can fulfill my sorting needs?

Edit: I'm sorting it like this:

```
const sortedData = _.sortBy(items, function (item) {
    return item.name;
});
```

Edit 2: To make it more clear, i need to sort it in chronological order where '3M' == 3 months, '1Y' == 1 year etc. And all that I have to work with is the 'name'-key

Edit 3: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my code example!

Comment: What is the logic for sorting? Is that `3M` = 3 months and `1Y` = 1 year and so on?

Comment: please add valid data structures.

Comment: @adiga Yes that is correct, I need to sort it in 
chronological order

Comment: Please add a valid input data. The object has duplicate keys. Do you have an array of objects with `name` as key?

Comment: One approach could be to convert your input years and month into the respective days value.
Exampe: 1y => 365, 3m => 90
Then sort by these values

Comment: @adiga I've updated my code example now!

Comment: @NinaScholz Added! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `localeCompare()` and `replace()`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RWnPT0/1)**

```js
const items = [{name:'LFB 10Y GF'},{name:'LFB 1Y GF'},{name:'LFB 2Y GF'},{name:'LFB 3M GF'},{name:'LFB 5Y GF'}]

const result = items.sort((a, b) => {
  a = a.name.replace(/(\d+)(.)/, '$2$1')
  b = b.name.replace(/(\d+)(.)/, '$2$1')
  
  return a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {numeric: true})
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

By having an array with strings or similar data structures, you could get the part of the string with a number and a unit, get the value based on one day and take the delta of the days as result for the sorting callback.

```js
const
    getDays = ([count, unit]) => {
        var times = { D: 1, M: 30, Y: 365 };
        return count * times[unit];
    },
    getPart = s => s.match(/(\d+)([DMY])(?=\s)/).slice(1),
    items = ['LFB 5Y GF', 'LFB 3M GF', 'LFB 2Y GF', 'LFB 10Y GF', 'LFB 3Y GF'];

items.sort((a, b) => getDays(getPart(a)) - getDays(getPart(b)));

console.log(items);
```